# Filtering elements in a jQuery set based on their parent node

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filtering, subset

Suppose I have two containers with the same CSS applied to them and their sub items.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="dummy">distrating item</div> <!-- dummy one -->
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="dummy">distrating item</div> <!-- dummy one -->
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    ...
</div>
```

This is of course na example. but the point being is this. If I define a jQuery selector as:

```
$(".wrapper .item")
```

and then write a jQuery plugin that should do something with these items but per container, how am I suppose to get a subset of items from the whole set that belong to each container?

```
$.fn.extend({
    randomize: function() {
        if (this.length > 1)
        {
            var set = this;
            var origSelect = set.selector;
            var containers = this.parent();
            $.each(containers, function() {
                var container = $(this);
                var items = set.filter(?????);
                ....
            });
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Based on the data that I have in the inner function:

- whole set
- original element selector
- current container

Is there some jQuery selector that can help me get a subset of items from the whole set that belong to a particular item.

### First possibility

This of course doesn't work:

```
$(origSelect, container);
```

which is equivalent to

```
$(".wrapper .item", ".wrapper");
```

because container CSS class is part of original selector. If it wasn't it would work. but I can't control that.

### Second possibility

Filtering by

```
container.children();
```

will also fail because it will also select *dummy* items.

But the idea is to reuse existing jQuery set which is of course faster than selecting DOM nodes all over again which is done in both cases.

So basically I want something like:

```
set.filter(something);
```

But I don't know if there's filter for what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the parent elements of each item to your current container element:

```
$.each(containers, function() {
    var container = $(this);
    var items = set.filter(function() {
        return this.parentNode == container[0];
    });
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Uhmmm. This could be it. Why didn't you just use `return $(this).closest(container).length == 1`?

Comment: @Robert, good point, I guess I was too focused on the `.wrapper` class :) I personally think testing `length` makes the intent somewhat less clear, though.

Comment: My items **are always direct children of their containers** because containers are retrieved in this line `var containers = this.parent();` as can be seen in my code. Using `parent()` as you suggested could only be used with DOM element comparison since you can only provide string selector to `parent([selector])` function. But it could still be faster on those items that should be filtered out. Especially when items are deep in DOM tree so `closest` would traverse a lot of nodes.

Comment: @Robert, actually `closest()` stops at the first element that matches the selector (unlike `parents()`). You're right about the call to `parent()` in your question, though, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: FYI: I've published a public jQuery plugin that does transposition. Check my [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/07/use-css-floats-to-flow-data-in-columns.html) about it and get the code if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$.fn.extend({
    randomize: function() {
        if (this.length > 1)
        {
            var set = this;
            var origSelect = set.selector;
            var selectorArr = origSelect.split(" ");
            var itemSelector = selectorArr[selectorArr.length - 1];
            var containers = this.parent();
            $.each(containers, function() {
                var container = $(this);
                var items = container.filter(itemSelector);
                ....
            });
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work, since all items in the set satisfy condition `.item` hence your filtering would return complete set.

Comment: Nope won't work. `container` is always just a single element. Filtering on it makes no sense. You probably wanted to write `container.children(itemSelector)` but in this case it would be better to just use `container.children(origSelect)` which would return correct items. The problem is that original set is not reused so element selection has to be performed all over again.

Comment: FYI: I've published a public jQuery plugin that does transposition. Check my [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/07/use-css-floats-to-flow-data-in-columns.html) about it and get the code if you need it.